# Expected freetype version 2.6.1. Found freetype version 2.9.1. python

Tags: python, matplotlib, freetype, freetype-py

Matplotlib is not built with the correct FreeType version to run tests.  Set local_freetype=True in setup.cfg and rebuild. Expect many image comparison failures below. Expected freetype version 2.6.1. Found freetype version 2.9.1. Freetype build type is not local
Traceback

. I all ready try put in Setup.cfg :

```
[packages]
tests = True
toolkits_tests = True

[test]
local_freetype = True
```

. Uninstall and install matplotlib

. In the back end I have 'TkAgg'\

. Matplotlib Testdata spouse in pip is install 
Requirement already satisfied: testdata in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)

ImportError("Matplotlib test data is not installed")
ImportError: Matplotlib test data is not installed
[Finished in 3.1s]